# Weekly Topic: Gear Storage

Tags: discussion

This week it's questions related to storing gear for the next season

(Sorry for this being late guys).

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

A:  Each sleeping bag has a cardboard box that it can fit in lightly stuffed.  Those boxes are on top of a set of shelves to make it harder for the mice to find them.

B:  Boots are cleaned, oiled if appropriate, and stored on one of the shelves.

C:  Special purpose gear (canoe bag, life jacket, water booties, and consolidated into a bag or duffle.

D:  I have an old trunk that gets clothing that is multi-activity -- e.g. scarfs, long johns, parka, fleeces...

E:  Snowshoes, paddles, skiis are put on the rafters in the breezeway over the porch.  Ideally these come down when *really* dry for any repair, varnish etc.  This keeps them out of reach of mice (who love both the salt on paddle grips, and the babiche on snowshoes.)

I don't climb now, but when I did, then ropes were washed, dried, and measured to see that they were within some small percentage of the nominal length. (The idea was to catch any hard falls that had stretched the rope) Duct tape on the end was checked to see that the 'year bought' was still readable.

Comment: Hey Sherwood!  This was actually a weekly topic a while back.  Weekly Topics were just suggested themes.  Which reminds me...